# What pronouns are used in German for a transgender person?

Tags: pronoun

In English, it is common in some circles to encounter the 3rd person plural pronoun, they, in a first person singular context when the person is transgender.

For example:  I see [name] walking down the street. They look happy today.

Is the German language usage changing to handle people of both/neither genders?

Comment: As far as I am aware, _they_ is used if the preferred pronoun is unknown.

Comment: Does that mean that my sentence would be translated as "Ich sehe [Name] die Straße entlang gehen. sie sehen heute glücklich aus?"

Comment: No, I was speaking about the English language.

Answer (score 7):

The following pronouns have been suggested by different parties to replace the existing gendered pronouns:

A, as, bla, dey, die, el, em, en, eos, es, er_sie, ey/em, er/sie with opposite gender description, et, hän, hen, iks, ind, k, le, nin, per, sel, Ser, sier, sir, they, vii, Vorname (using the first name), why, x, xier, xie/xieren, Zae, Ze/Zee, z/zet.

Usage and meaning are explained on [Nichtbinär Wiki](https://nibi.space/pronomen). None of these pronouns will be understood outside the LGBT+ community, and most not even there.

---

There seems to be an influx of questions about gender-neutral language on this site recently. The answer to all these questions is:

There is an ongoin attempt in mostly academic and political circles to establish a language without gender-bias. Some media have begun to implement some strategies, but the general public did not yet adopt them, and none of these forms are considered grammatically correct, yet.

The Wikipedia article on *[Geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache)* and the other articles linked from there give a good overview of the current situation.

Comment: I would say the opposite is true: Some political circles try to establish a language which is engineered around gender-bias.

Comment: Danke. Ich war neugierig, weil Deutsch so eine geschlechtsspezifische Sprache ist.